# How do I connect my HTML textbox input to my Javascript filter POST code?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, filter

I have been using some API's to obtain information from the following test link: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos in which according to the ID I insert, I obtain the information into a customizable card-like box.

I wish to add a textbox where my input will be the ID that the code will recieve. How can I achieve this?

I have the following HTML code, with the Textbox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>My Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            ID Filter:
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="id_filter" value="">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <button id="btn" type="button" class="mt-3 mx-auto btn btn-primary"> Get Post </button>
            </div>

            <div class="row" id="cardDiv"></div>
        </form>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript code, where I'm struggling to figure out how to fetch my Textbox input, and put it in between the brackets:

```
var $btn = document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", getPost);
var $div = document.getElementById("cardDiv");

function getPost() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    .then((res)=> {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((post)=> {
            $div.innerHTML +=`
            <div class="card col-3 m-1 mx-auto">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="${post[0].thumbnailUrl}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <b class="card-id"> ID: ${post[0].id} </b>
                    <br>
                    <b class="card-album"> Album: ${post[0].albumId} </b>
                    <h5 class="card-title"> ${post[0].title} </h5>
                    <u class="card-url"> ${post[0].thumbnailUrl} </u>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
    })
}
```

How can I dinamically transfer my input towards the Textbox upon pressing by button, towards the '0' value in between brackets?

Comment: Hi Ben, welcome to SO. Could you be more specific on what you want with your, I assume `<input type="text">` element. Do you want to *add a input*, *fetch an input* or *dynamically transfer the input towards the Textbox upon pressing by button*? Could you paint a picture of what the result would be? Pictures would help.

Comment: Hi @EmielZuurbier, currently all of the code is working if I manually insert the ID's within the brackets of the JS code. Although, I wish that the ID value could be the one I input within the textbox, where the result would appear from that textbox input inserted by the user. Picture: https://i.imgur.com/5fHH6K7.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adapted your example and modified it to display the post for the id input in the input box.

```js
var $btn = document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", getPost);
var $div = document.getElementById("cardDiv");
var $idInput = document.getElementById("id-filter");

function getPost() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    .then((res)=> {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((post)=> {
            var inputPostId = $idInput.value;
            var postForId = {};
            for(var i=0; i<post.length; i++) {
               if(post[i].id == inputPostId) {
                  postForId = post[i];
                  break;
               }
            }
            $div.innerHTML +=`
            <div class="card col-3 m-1 mx-auto">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="${postForId.thumbnailUrl}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <b class="card-id"> ID: ${postForId.id} </b>
                    <br>
                    <b class="card-album"> Album: ${postForId.albumId} </b>
                    <h5 class="card-title"> ${postForId.title} </h5>
                    <u class="card-url"> ${postForId.thumbnailUrl} </u>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>My Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            ID Filter:
            <br>
            <input type="text" id="id-filter" name="id_filter" value="1">
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <button id="btn" type="button" class="mt-3 mx-auto btn btn-primary"> Get Post </button>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="cardDiv"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the `input` in which you fill in the id of your image. This will make it easy to select later on.

```
<input type="text" id="image-id" name="id_filter" value="">
```

Select that input field in JavaScript. Whenever the button is clicked you will need the value that is in that field to get the image with the corresponding ID.

```
var imageIdFilter = document.getElementById('image-id');

var $btn = document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", getPost);
var $div = document.getElementById("cardDiv");
```

Now whenever you call the `getPost` function extract the `value` from the `input`. Put this `value` at the end of your API URL. Requesting a single image will produce a different response. Earlier you would receive an array of object, now it is just a single object. So all `post[0]` have be turned into `post`, since it is not an array anymore.

Decide for yourself if you want to either **add** an image or **replace** an image by changing the `$div.innerHTML +=` to `$div.innerHTML =` (notice the missing + operator).

```
function getPost() {
    const id = imageIdFilter.value;
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/${id}`)
    .then((res)=> {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then((post)=> {
        $div.innerHTML +=`
            <div class="card col-3 m-1 mx-auto">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="${post.thumbnailUrl}">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <b class="card-id"> ID: ${post.id} </b>
                    <br>
                    <b class="card-album"> Album: ${post.albumId} </b>
                    <h5 class="card-title"> ${post.title} </h5>
                    <u class="card-url"> ${post.thumbnailUrl} </u>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
    });
}
```

I hope this is of any help.